# Node.js: mysql pool, Error: connect ETIMEDOUT

Tags: mysql, nodejs, express, npm

tengo la siguiente conexión en el servidor node.js (usando express)
`config.ts`

```js
const mysql = require('mysql');

const config = {
  host     : 'ip',
  user     : 'user',
  password : 'pass',
  database : 'db'
};

export const pool = mysql.createPool(config);
```

en el archivos de rutas tengo `router.ts`

```
import { pool } from '../database/config';

router.get('/data', (req: Request, res: Response) => {

        pool.query('SELECT 1 + 1 AS solution', function(err, rows, fields) {
          if (err) throw err;
          console.log('The solution is: ', rows[0].solution);
        });


    res.json({ok: true});
});
```

la conexión a MySQL (base de datos MySQL está en un hosting de paga, tambien tengo la ip) Se establece y puedo hacer consultas pero si dejo mas de 24 horas encendido el servidor(El servidor node.js lo tengo en mi computadora y tengo una ip publica funcionando) me arroja el siguiente error pasado un buen tiempo

```
Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
    at PoolConnection.Connection._handleConnectTimeout (C:\Users\Desarrollo\Desktop\01-server\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:412:13)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:286:20)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at Socket._onTimeout (net.js:442:8)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:436:11)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:300:5)
    at listOnTimeout (timers.js:263:5)
    at Timer.processTimers (timers.js:223:10)
--------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (C:direccionServidor\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:144:48)
    at Protocol.handshake (C:direccionServidor\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:51:23)
    at PoolConnection.connect (C:direccionServidor\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:119:18)
    at Pool.getConnection (C:direccionServidor\node_modules\mysql\lib\Pool.js:48:16)
    at Pool.query (C:direccionServidor\node_modules\mysql\lib\Pool.js:202:8)
    at exports.router.get (C:direccionServidor\dist\routes\router.js:45:23)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:direccionServidor\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:direccionServidor\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (C:direccionServidor\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:direccionServidor\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
```

para este punto el servidor se cae o ya no sigue funcionando por este error, ¿ cuál es el error que estoy cometiendo o omitiendo al realizar este tipo de conexion (pool)?

Comment: intenta conectarte con un programa, tal vez workbench , verifica que los servicios estén funcionando, si lo estan ,verifica los parametros de conexion probablemente tienes un error alli

Comment: Entiendo, los parámetros de conexión están funcionando y los servicios, hago consultas y me da los resultados esperados pero pasando un tiempo sin hacer nada manda el error antes mencionado.

Comment: entonces creo que deberias chequear el log de mysql

Comment: Perfecto revisaré para ver si encuentro algo inusual, gracias por la sugerencias.